# Plone CMS: how heavy are search requests compared to typical CMS GET requests?

Tags: search, plone

Plone CMS: how heavy are search requests compared to typical CMS GET requests?

I fear that on a large site (0.5 milions of documents) enabling search capability is asking for DOS. If so, how this threat can be mitigated? Can search work on a different ZOE instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plone's portal_catalog is rather efficient/fast/optimized. It's not like an SQL Query where you can construct searches that take minutes to complete.

The heavy part is usually "waking up" objects when presenting the search results, you should work as much as possible with the metadata (so called "brains") that the catalog returns. This is what Plone tries to do by default anyway.

But still, you can use a seperate ZEO instance for handling search request if you feel that this may be a bottleneck. Just make sure requests for /search and /search_form (or generically, /search*) end up at this specific ZEO instance. How you do this is rather specific to your current load balancing setup (apache, squid, nginx, etc)

Answer (score 3):

With that many documents you want to be investigating a dedicated search system - Plone's text indexes are really not that great. Take a look at http://plone.org/products/collective.solr for a Plone integration with http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ or http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.gsa if you have a Google Search Appliance.

Answer (score 2):

Plone's search engine is awesome in that it is fully integrated and ships with the default install. When your site grows to areas of 500k documents you generally want a more solid search.

We have used SOLR with great success is large projects, and there already exist several integrations with Plone:

http://plone.org/products/collective.solr 
http://plone.org/products/alm.solrindex
http://plone.org/products/collective.recipe.solrinstance